# Linking classes with metafunctions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

Consider

```
class B;  class C;

class A {
    using linked_from = std::tuple<B,C>;  // i.e. A is "linked from" B and C.
};

class B {
    using linked_to = std::tuple<A,C>;  // i.e. B is "linked to" A and C.
};

class C {
    using linked_to = std::tuple<A>;
    using linked_from = std::tuple<B>;
};
```

What I want to do is redesign the above so that there is no maintenance responsibilities whenever the `linked_to` member types are changed.  Perhaps something along the lines of

```
template <typename To, typename From>
struct LinkFromMap {
    using linked_from = From;
};

template <typename From, typename To>
struct LinkPair : LinkFromMap<To, From> {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Link : LinkPair<Ts, T>... {
    using linked_to = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

class B;  class C;

class A {};

class B : public Link<B, A,C> {};

class C : public Link<C, A> {};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<B::linked_to, std::tuple<A,C>>::value, "");
    // Still need to obtain std::tuple<B,C> from A,  std::tuple<B> from C, etc...
}
```

`A` and `C` do not need to keep their `linked_from` member types, as long as `std::tuple<B,C>` can be obtained from `A` and `std::tuple<B>` can be obtained from C.  That is why I've defined `LinkFromMap` above, but I can't figure out how to use `LinkFromMap` to achieve that.  Can it be used at the end somehow to form the packs `<A, B,C>` and `<C,B>` or something like that?  Or is there a better way to automate type retrievals that `linked_from` was designed for?

Comment: Eek. I'm skeptical there's a way to do this, but the template metaprogramming extremists may prove me wrong. Also, what's the point?

Comment: If it were possible, then the type of `magic_get_linked_from<A>` would depend on the class definitions seen before it. That means a stateful metaprogram, which C++ isn't intended to support. Compare [CWG 2118](http://wg21.link/cwg2118). If you know the full list of types to be considered - e.g., `get_linked_from<A, std::tuple<A,B,C>>` - this can be done.

Comment: Ok, solved using T.C.'s method.  But if there is a method that does not call for using `std::tuple<Every darn class>`, I would be very interested in seeing it.

Comment: How could you possibly know about the other classes? You have to "store" it somewhere. Create a wrapper if you don't want to hardcode it everywhere.